# Spring @Autowired EntityManager failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am studying Spring JPA integration and come up with strange behavior when trying to autowire `EntityManager` with `@Autowired` annotation.

I have a Spring test that has no Spring Boot context support:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class JpaTransactionScopedPersistentContextTests {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "packages"
    })
    static class TestConfiguration {}

    @Autowired
    private EntityAService entityAService;

    @Test
    void testEntityManagerWithoutTransaction () {

        EntityA entityA = new EntityA();

        entityAService.save(entityA);
    }
}
```

The service is defined as follows:

```java
    @Service
    public class EntityAService {
    
//        @PersistenceContext - this works
        @Autowired // this fails
        private EntityManager entityManager;
    
        public EntityA save (EntityA entityA) {
            return entityManager.merge(entityA);
        }
    
        @Transactional
        public EntityA saveInTransaction (EntityA entityA) {
            return entityManager.merge(entityA);
        }
    }
```

I have the following JPA configuration:

```java
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationA {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceWithEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder () throws SQLException {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setName("test")
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScripts("classpath:/schema.sql")
            .addScripts("classpath:/data.sql")
            .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory (DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("packages");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager (EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Spring throws an error:

`No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of debugging a bunch of internal Spring code I have found the reason.

This:

```java
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Works only when you have `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.

For example:

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationA {}
```

That is, autowiring of `EntityManager` is a feature that is provided by Spring Data JPA module. It is not provided by usual Spring JPA integration.

Comment: You can use `@PersistenceContext` to inject an `EntityManager` without using Spring Data JPA. This is shown in the [Spring Framework reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#dao-annotations).